# I get an error when republishing the image I shot with ros2 run ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, decode, ros2

I get the following errors when republishing the image I took with ros2 run ffmpeg.;

```
ros2 run image_transport republish ffmpeg in/ffmpeg:=image_raw/ffmpeg raw out:=image_raw/uncompressed --ros-args -p "ffmpeg_image_transport.map.hevc_rkmpp:=hevc"`



terminate called after throwing an instance of 'image_transport::TransportLoadException'
  what():  Unable to load plugin for transport 'image_transport/ffmpeg_sub', error string:
According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class image_transport/ffmpeg_sub with base class type image_transport::SubscriberPlugin does not exist. Declared types are  image_transport/compressedDepth_sub image_transport/compressed_sub image_transport/raw_sub image_transport/theora_sub
[ros2run]: Aborted
```

I don't want to replace the parameters specified in the errors. I want to do this with ffmpeg. how can i fix this

After running ros2, I want to list the topics, echo them and view them with rviz2 and image uncompressed.Afterwards, I want to use and show this uncompressed image in my Python detection project.

Comment: This is off-topic, as it's not about programming. The tag-infos of [ffmpeg] and [ros2] contain information about where you could post your question. Just hover the mouse pointer over the tags to read the tag-info.